# How to redirect full url to subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect a site page to a subdomain (same url) with `.htaccess` but it's stuck in a redirect loop or redirected to 404 page. The following is my code used in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^uk.example.com/2-day-course.html http://www.example.com/2-day-course.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Some of the URLs need to be redirected from subdomain to main domain on the same page, it has the same issue like above.

Is there a way to do it with `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

If this is resulting in a redirect loop then I assume `uk.example.com` and `www.example.com` must be pointing to the same place. You need to explicitly check the *host* before redirecting:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uk\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^2-day-course\.html$ http://www.example.com/2-day-course.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only. This does not include the *hostname*, which must be checked in a separate condition.

As always with 301 redirects, you'll need to clear all caches before testing.